# NSWindow that is unaffected by Expose

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, macos-carbon

Is there any way to make a window completely unaffected by Expose, just like the Dock? Setting the level to NSDockWindowLevel doesn't help. I know about NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary, but I want the window not to fade when Expose is active.

If it is not possible, is there any way to "unfade" the window after Expose fades it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way as far as I know.

Also, there's no reliable way to know that you're in Expose mode.